# Excel macro script stopped working, shows a busy mouse icon while running but does nothing to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I was using this macro to clean up show titles and sort season and episode numbers into their own columns. It was working great!

I haven't run it for about 6 months and now when I open the spreadsheet and try to run it, it just spins with a busy circle.

I'm at a total loss as to what would cause this macro to just not work. I haven't made any changes to the code since the last time I ran it and it did work.

Excel 2016

I've checked the References and fairly sure I've included all the necessary ones.

References: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRcan.png

I've tried stepping through (F8) the Macro to figure out where the problem is happening but it seems none of the macro is working, although it is running.

```
Sub cleanTitles()

Dim strTitle As String, regEx As New RegExp, strPattern As String
Dim strSeason As String, strEpisode As String, strYear As String

With regEx
.Global = True

Dim j As Integer: j = 2
While Not Range("A" & j).Value = vbNullString

If Range("F" & j).Value = vbNullString Then

strTitle = Range("A" & j).Value

.Pattern = "[Ss]\s?(\d{1,2})[xX\s]?[Ee]\s?(\d{1,2}).*"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count = 0 Then
.Pattern = "[\W_ ](\d{1,2})\s?[xX]\s?(\d{1,2}).*"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
End If
If Matches.Count = 0 Then
    Range("F" & j) = vbNullString
    Range("G" & j) = vbNullString
Else
    strSeason = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
    strEpisode = Matches(0).SubMatches(1)
    Range("F" & j) = strSeason
    Range("G" & j) = strEpisode
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, vbNullString)
End If

.Global = True
.Pattern = "\{[^\}]*\}[\W_]?"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, vbNullString)
End If
.Pattern = "\[[^\]]*\][\W_]?"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, vbNullString)
End If
.Pattern = "\([^\)]*\)[\W_]?"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, vbNullString)
End If
.Global = False

.Pattern = "[\W_](\d{4}).*"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
    strYear = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
    If strYear <= "1920" Then
        Range("F" & j) = Left(strYear, 2)
        Range("G" & j) = Right(strYear, 2)
    End If
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, vbNullString)
End If

.Pattern = "(\d{4})$"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, vbNullString)
End If

.Pattern = "^\d+-?([a-zA-Z])"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
    strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, Matches(0).SubMatches(0))
End If

.Global = True
.Pattern = "([a-z0-9])([A-Z])"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, "$1" & " " & "$2")
.Pattern = "([a-zA-Z])([0-9])"
Set Matches = .Execute(strTitle)
strTitle = .Replace(strTitle, "$1" & " " & "$2")
.Global = False


Range("A" & j) = IIf(strTitle <> vbNullString, strTitle, ".")

End If

j = j + 1
Wend

End With

End Sub
```

--- Example show titles to be cleaned ---
 The Big Bang Theory Season 10 Episode 15: The Locomotion Reverberation
The Big Bang Theory Season 10 Episode 16: The Allowance Evaporation
 The 100 Season 3 Episode 2:  Wanheda: Part Two
The Big Bang Theory Season 10 Episode 19: The Collaboration Fluctuation
The 100 Season 3 Episode 3:  Ye Who Enter Here
 The Good Doctor Season 1 Episode 12: Islands Part Two

The macro is supposed to delete text such as "Season" or "Episode" from column A and then take the corresponding numbers and add them to column F and G.
It is also supposed to delete punctuation such as ":"

Example result, ignore non-highlighted columns https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ym7N.png

Comment: Hard to fully diagnose but I see too things that could cause problems. One is unqualified range objects `Range("A" & j).Value`. Explicitly set that to a specific parent object (worksheet). The other is that your loop may be infinite, well, not infinite most likely in this case, but it may be looping more than you expect. Step through the code line-by-line (debug) and see if the actions taken are the actions expected and then adjust as needed.

Comment: You may not have changed the script, but you might have changed the data the script was designed for... see if you can find a copy of your data as it was when the script was working, and compare to what you have now... and what's different. Other than that, stepping through is always a good idea, not sure what you mean by "none of the macro is working, although it is running", it either works or throws an error. Add an `Option Explicit` at the top, might highlight your issue faster.

Comment: The code seems to be working fine, it runs just one loop but  it just doesn't get any matches. Try revising your regexes.

Comment: FAB, I added option explicit and there weren't any undefined variables . -- 

ScottHoltzman, wouldn't an unqualified range just refer to the sheet attached to the macro by default? There are no other sheets or workbooks open  --

@Yane You get it and I think you are correct, although I am baffled that it can't get any matches, even when using the exact same data I was using 6 months ago.